# Performance of List<struct> vs List<class>

Tags: c#, memory-management, struct, clr, prefetch

Out of curiosity, I was trying to test the performance of `List<T>` using both `value` and `reference` types.

The results were not as I expected, leading me to believe my understanding of how these objects are laid out in memory might not be correct.

This was my experiment:

- Create a basic `class` containing just two members, an `int` and a `bool`
- Create 2 `List<T>` objects to hold my test classes (`List1` and `List2`)
- Randomly generate test objects and add them to `List1` and `List2` alternately
- Time how long it takes to iterate through `List1` (doing some arbitrary work such as incrementing a counter and then accessing the element)

I then repeated with a `struct` in place of a `class`

My assumptions were that when using a `class`, the references held in the `List<T>` would be contiguous, but because of how I created them (switching between adding to `List1` and `List2`), the objects they point to probably wouldn't be.

I thought that when using a `struct`, because it is a value type, the objects themselves would be held contiguously in memory (since the `List<T>` holds the actual items rather than a collection of references).

Because of this, I expected `struct` to perform better (due to prefetchers etc..)

In actual fact, both were very similar.

What's going on here?

**Edit - Added code to actually access the element in the iterator, code sample included**

Test class (or struct)

```
public class/struct TestClass
{
    public int TestInt;
    public bool TestBool;
}
```

Creating random Lists:

```
var list1 = new List<TestClass>();
var list2 = new List<TestClass>();

var toggle = false;
for (var i=0; i < 4000000; i++)
{
    // Random object generation removed for simplicity

    if (toggle)
        list1.Add(randomObject);
    else
        list2.Add(randomObject);

    toggle = !toggle;    
}
```

Testing:

```
var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
var counter = 0;
var testBool = false;

stopwatch.Start();

foreach(var item in list1)
{
    // Access the element
    testBool = item.TestBool;
    counter++;
}

stopwatch.Stop();
```

Repeat with `TestObject` as both a `class` and a `struct`.

I realise there isn't much difference, but I expected `struct` to perform significantly better than `class`

Comment: Show us your benchmark

Comment: Micro-benchmarks like this are notoriously unreliable.  The code is just too fast, something as simple as a misaligned branch target can make a big difference.  Standard mistakes are measuring the jitting time and not repeating the test at least 10 times.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks I tried accessing the element (code sample and metrics updated) performance appears to be more equal. I still expected the `struct`to perform better but perhaps, as you say, this test just isn't representative of a real scenario.

Comment: @HansPassant Could you suggest how I could benchmark this properly please, or is it just not likely to ever give real results in a simplified example such as this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
// Access the element
testBool = item.TestBool;
```

That has no effect, the optimizer will remove the statement since it has no useful side-effects.  You are not actually measuring the difference between a struct and a class since you never actually access the element.

```
counter++;
```

Same story, pretty likely to be optimized away.  Unless you actually *use* the counter value, after the loop completes.  Having the optimizer remove too much code and make the test meaningless is a common micro-benchmark hazard.  A workaround would be:

```
foreach(var item in list1)
{
    // Access the element
    counter += item.TestInt;
}
Console.WriteLine(counter);
```

Benchmark guidelines are:

- Only profile code produced by the Release configuration.  The Debug build produces too much extra code and suppresses optimization
- Tools + Options, Debugging, General, untick the "Suppress JIT optimization on module load".  This ensures that you get optimized code even if you run with the debugger
- Debug + Windows + Disassembly is a very important debugger window to show you what code *really* runs.  Having some understanding of machine code is required to interpret that window correctly
- Very important to put an outer loop around the test code to ensure that you run the test at least 10 times.  This removes cold start effects, like the processor having to fill the L1 instruction cache and the jitter having to load the IL from the assembly and compile it the first time it executes.  And removes random outliers you'll get from having to compete with other processes that run on the machine and also compete for the processor.
- Differences of 15% are not statistically significant.

Answer (score 7):

If you aren't actually accessing members of the class objects stored in your list, then the following two types should provide equivalent performance for iteration.

1. `List<IntPtr>`
2. `List<object>`

Even though the reference type *instances* aren't filling a contiguous section of memory, the *references* themselves are.

The exception to the above case would be if the CLR compresses pointers when executing 64-bit applications with less than 32GiB of memory. This strategy is documented as [Compressed OOPS](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/CompressedOops) in the JVM. However, the x86-64 instruction set includes instructions that allow this compression/decompression to be performed *extremely* efficiently, so even in this case you should see performance similar to `List<int>`.

Things get interesting when your value types exceed the size of a pointer (`IntPtr.Size`). After that point, the performance of a `List<T>` containing references should quickly surpass the performance of a `List<T>` of value types. This is due to the fact that regardless of how big your reference type *instance* is, the *reference* to that instance is at most `IntPtr.Size`.

Comment: Do you know if any x64 implementations of .NET use 32-bit references?  I've long thought that optimal performance would be obtained if code could use the larger register file of x64 without having to use 64-bit references, since the latter gobble up a lot more cache space than 32-bit ones.  Further, the best way to go beyond 4GB would have been to have had x86 support 32-bit segment registers, where the upper bits would be a descriptor-selector and the lower bits a scalable offset.  That could have allowed some parts of the memory map to have segments on 4-byte boundaries, while other parts...

Comment: ...had then on larger (e.g. 4K) boundaries, making it possible to access many gigs worth of objects whose individual size could be a couple gigs each, all while using 32-bit segments and 32-bit offsets.